# How to printf multiline output in place?

Tags: bash, printf, echo

I'd like to print multiline output in place if it's posible.  I have a simple for loop like this:

```
for i in {1..100}; do
  OUTP=`df -h |grep sda`
  echo -ne "$OUTP\r"
  sleep 5
done
```

I would like to get output:

```
/dev/sda2       110G  9.0G   96G   9% /mnt/sdb
/dev/sda1      1022M  248M  775M  25% /mnt/sdb/boot/efi
```

and to be replaced with new sizes, as I'm syncing files.
but instead  I'm getting:

```
/dev/sda2       110G   19G   87G  18% /mnt/sdb
/dev/sda2       110G   19G   86G  18% /mnt/sdb/boot/efi
/dev/sda2       110G   19G   86G  18% /mnt/sdb/boot/efi
/dev/sda2       110G   19G   86G  19% /mnt/sdb/boot/efi
/dev/sda2       110G   20G   85G  19% /mnt/sdb/boot/efi
```

It is jumping back only one line and replacing previous line, and keeps adding one line when there is only output of two lines.  When output 3 lines it would add extra 2 lines like following:

```
/dev/sda2       110G   49G   56G  47% /mnt/sdb
/dev/sda1      1022M  248M  775M  25% /mnt/sdb/boot/efi
/dev/sda3       299G  949M  283G   1% /mnt/sdb/var
/dev/sda2       110G   49G   56G  47% /mnt/sdb
/dev/sda1      1022M  248M  775M  25% /mnt/sdb/boot/efi
/dev/sda3       299G  1.5G  282G   1% /mnt/sdb/var
/dev/sda2       110G   49G   56G  47% /mnt/sdb
/dev/sda1      1022M  248M  775M  25% /mnt/sdb/boot/efi
/dev/sda3       299G  1.9G  282G   1% /mnt/sdb/var
/dev/sda2       110G   49G   56G  47% /mnt/sdb
/dev/sda1      1022M  248M  775M  25% /mnt/sdb/boot/efi
/dev/sda3       299G  2.4G  281G   1% /mnt/sdb/var
```

And so on.
I tried \r\r but no luck.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show sample input, actual output and desired output ? Please edit your question, don't add those info in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different terminal command sequences for that sort of thing.  You *might* be able to save the cursor position and restore it with:

```
$ tput sc; printf 'multi\nline\noutput\n'; tput rc; printf '%s' 'overwrite line 1'; echo; echo; echo
overwrite line 1
line
output
```

For your case, that becomes:

```
tput sc     # Save cursor position
for i in {1..100}; do
  outp=$(df -h |grep sda)
  printf '%s' "$outp"
  tput rc   # Restore cursor position
done
```

Note that it is bad practice to use ALL_CAPS for variable names, and also that the variable here is totally unnecessary (unless you wish to retain the data for use later in the script).  You could easily do:

```
for i ...; do
  tput sc
  df -h | grep sda
  tput rc
done
```

Comment: Thanks @William  this example I tried and it only jumps back one line like with using '\r'

Comment: If output starts when the cursor is near the bottom of the terminal, that is the behavior you will see.  Trying running `clear` first to position the cursor near the top of the display.

Comment: Hey @William, yes with clear is working properly.  Is it possible to just jump back simply 2 or 3  lines?

Comment: Yes. To move up 3 lines, use `tput cuu 3` (cuu == cursor up).  To put the cursor at line L of column C, use `tput cup $L $C` (cup == cursor position)